# Django & South: Adding new field but DatabaseError occurs "table already exists"

Tags: python, django, django-south

In trying to add a new field to a preexisting Model/table, I get a DatabaseError with 'table already exists.' I have run migrations before this one so I am a bit puzzled why adding a new field would pop up this error.

Commands executed:

```
python manage.py schemamigration app --auto
python manage.py migrate app
```

Previous SO questions like this were answered with faking a migration.

```
python manage.py migrate app --fake
python manage.py migrate app
```

The problem that arises from this is that the column is not created. So when you runserver, you will see a DatabaseError 'no such column'.

As far as my model, I am only adding a CharField.

Thanks in advance for your help-

Comment: I commented out the field, ran schemamigration, then migrate. Uncommented out the field, ran schemamigration, then migrate and it worked. Not sure what I was doing wrong :/

Answer (score 12):

You need to do `schemamigration app --initial` first *without* your new field, then `migrate app --fake 0001` (or whichever migration number it returned) to set the south database to that  state (tables already created).

Add your new field, *then* run `schemamigration myapp --auto`, *then* migrate.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Been scratching my head on this for a while!

Comment: using MySQL and still asspain :/

Answer (score 1):

I commented out the field, ran schemamigration, then migrate. Uncommented out the field, ran schemamigration, then migrate and it worked. Not sure what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you doing something on migration and did not let south knows about it.

If you looking at the south_* table in the database, you will find-out south keeps logs about db migrations in the database. The common way is to faking the migration.
There is a `fake` argument for the South.

here you can find out what is all about:
http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#options